# Parsing a date from a JTextField in GUI to arrayList

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I have developed a GUI for entering text into a `JTextFields`, which is then saved in an `arrayList`.

I set all of my variables to type String in order to get this working. I know want to change the types. For my `DateOfBirth`, I have changed this to type `Date` (as I have set up a Date class).

The code for iterating through the arrayList is now breaking down at `.setText`. See below:

`birthField.setText(aList.get(i).getDateOfBirth());`
`birthField.setText(aList.get(aList.size()-1).getDateOfBirth());`

These were working previously for Strings. I get the error message 'The Method setText(String) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (Date).

What am I doing wrong. I feel I need to parse the date but I am a little lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a JSpinner and there are even same date picker components available if your search for them

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `Date` objects to `String`. You can use `DateFormat` for that, here is an example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
birthField.setText(df.format(aList.get(i).getDateOfBirth()));
```

And to convert the `String` value back to a `Date` object, you can do this:

```
Date dateOfBirth = df.parse(birthField.getText());
```

Comment: This is perfect. It has fixed almost all of my issues. Thanks very much @Titus. Only issue now is:

`db = birthField.getText();`

This is now breaking down. How can I incorporate the date format into this? The error is: Type Mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date

Comment: I'm struggling to see where I need to add this. My issues seems to be that there is a java.util.Date but also my own Date class. My error is that it cannot convert from from java.util.Date to Date. 

Do I keep the `db = birthField.getText();` where it is? Where do I add your additional line of code? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JavaNewbie If you have created your own `Date` class, you won't be able to create those kind of object using `DateFormat`, I will need to know more about this class in order to suggest a solution. If your `Date` class contains a `java.util.Date` variable, you can do something like this: `aList.get(i).setDateOfBirth(df.parse(birthField.getText()));`